# Programmatically change IIS7's ApplicationHost.config on Windows 2008 64-bit

Tags: iis-7, 64-bit, windows-server-2008

I need my 32-bit InstallShield installer to make a change to ApplicationHost.config (Part of IIS7).  I want to set the value of overrideModeDefaults from "Deny" to "Allow" for the ipSecurity configSection.

This works fine in Windows 2008 32-bit, but not in Windows 2008 64-bit.  The problem is that the installer only looks in systemWOW64 for the file, but it is actually in system32.

Is there a way for me to edit this file programmatically from my 32-bit installer?  I'm okay with running a script or even doing it post-install with my 32-bit configuration tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found my own answer.  Turns out you can use %windir%\sysnative to access the system32 directory in a 32-bit application.